# phalcon dev tools system path variable

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to add phalcon dev tools to my path variables (As shown [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/devtools-installation)) but I'm getting this error (When I try to use phalcon in cmd):

```
ERROR: The environment variable PTOOLSPATH is outdated! Current value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\phalcon-devtools". New value: C:\Program Files (x86)\phalcon-devtools
```

This is my phalcon.bat:

```
@echo off

set PTOOLSPATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\phalcon-devtools"
php %PTOOLSPATH%\phalcon.php %*
```

My phalcon.php location is :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\phalcon-devtools
```

And lastly, my system variable is :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\phalcon-devtools
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. Looks like this is a bug. Could you please open an issue at [GitHub repo](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools)?

Answer (score 0):

change these

```
set PTOOLSPATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\phalcon-devtools"
php %PTOOLSPATH%\phalcon.php %*
```

to

```
set PTOOLSPATH=%~dp0
php %PTOOLSPATH%phalcon.php %*
```